# The click on the div element with role='button' isn't operate

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The click on the div element with role='button' isn't operate.I need to click on the icon, but I can't do it.

html:

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div role="button" tabindex="-1">
      <strong>ItemName2</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="d">
      <div class="item-icon" role="button" tabindex="-1"  style="display: none">
        <i aria-label="icon: edit" class="edit"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"> ... </div>
  <div class="item"> ... </div>
  <div class="item"> ... </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
  try {
    await driver.get("http://127.0.0.1");

    let findButtons = await driver.findElements(By.tagName('strong'));

    let buttons = findButtons.map(elem => elem.getText());
    const allButtons = await Promise.all(buttons);
    console.log(allButtons);             // It is displayed all button values, such as ItemName1
    let tButton;
    for (let i = 0; i < findButtons.length; i++) {
      if (allButtons[i] == 'ItemName2') {
        tButton = await findButtons[i];
        tButton.click();                // I try to click on this button, where value = ItemName2
        console.log(allButtons[i]);     //  It is displayed button value 'ItemName2'    
      }}}
```

Console error:

```
(node:12254) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add more to the Html part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
 let findButtons = await driver.findElements(By.tagName('strong'));

 let buttons = findButtons.map(async elem => await elem.getText()); // I add async & await
 const allButtons = await Promise.all(buttons);
 console.log(allButtons);   // There are all itemName
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting stale element exception because you are trying to get the element with old references. Each time you click on the element in your loop, the elements reference will be updated and `allButtons[i]` does not work. In order to handle this you have to get the latest refers of buttons. Try the below.

js:

```
const { By, Key, until } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
require("chromedriver");
async () => {
  let driver = await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
  try {
    await driver.get("http://10.203.201.77:8000/login");

    let findButtons = await driver.findElements(By.tagName('strong'));

    let buttons = findButtons.map(elem => elem.getText());
    const allButtons = await Promise.all(buttons);
    console.log(allButtons);             // It is displayed all button values, such as ItemName1
    let tButton;
    for (let i = 0; i < findButtons.length; i++) {
      buttons = findButtons.map(elem => elem.getText()); # getting the button so that the elements refererence will refresh
      if (allButtons[i] == 'ItemName2') {
        tButton = await findButtons[i];
        tButton.click();                // I try to click on this button, where value = ItemName2
        console.log(allButtons[i]);     //  It is displayed button value 'ItemName2'

      }
    }
      console.log("DONE");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } finally {
      await driver.quit();
    }
  }
}
```